# Linked list node combiner function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have this function that checks if the nodes in a linked list are physically next to each other, byte wise with their `start_byte` and `end_byte` variables. But my function keeps segfaulting and I'm not sure why, could anyone offer assistance?

```
void checkIfFreeTogether(void)
{
    FREEPTR l =freelist;
    FREEPTR f = freelist;
    FREEPTR g =freelist;
    int i = 0;

        while(f->next!=NULL)
    {

        if(f->end_byte+1==f->next->start_byte)
        {
                    cout << f << endl;

        f->size = f->size + f->next->size;
                cout << f << endl;

        f->end_byte = f->next->end_byte;
                cout << f << endl;
                cout << f->next << endl;


        f->next=f->next->next;

                cout << f << endl;
                cout << f->next << endl;

        }

            f=f->next;          

    }       

}
```

here is the output of this particular function, the couts used for debugging and showing the values

```
0x200583a8
0x200583a8
0x200583a8
0x20058438
0x200583a8
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `f->next->next` is null in this:

```
            f->next=f->next->next;

            cout << f << endl;
            cout << f->next << endl;
```

then you:

```
            f=f->next;
```

and the `while` crashes at the next iteration

so your `while` should be:

```
            while(f && f->next)
```

did you debug it?